# "Redefenition of 'Category' as a different kind of symbol" and conflict with Objc runtime class names

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I have got a class in Objective-C:

```
@interface Category : NSObject
{
// ...
}
```

All was good and **I've used this class with no problems in 3 different projects.**

Once I decided to create test target for one project. Then the strange thing occurred: compiler refuses to compile with this error:

```
Redefenition of 'Category' as a different kind of symbol
```

it also pointed to `runtime.h` with

```
typedef struct objc_category *Category;
```

Well, it is reasonable.

However, I can not understand why it allowed me to use this class before and what is the difference between original target and test target. I've checked `Deploy target`, `iOS SDK`, all macros, header paths, `#import <objc/runtime.h>` and classes in both targets - these are almost the same.

I don't want to refactor this class's name because of using it in multiples projects, so what can be the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly import `runtime.h` in a file using your own `Category` in the working target ? Just to see what happen.

Comment: @KIDdAe yes, a few files include `#import <objc/runtime.h>` (they are both in working and test targets)

Comment: well, sorry, I probably misunderstood you - but that did not helped too. I added this import into the file which uses my `Category`, still the same

Comment: Could it be some kind of undefined behaviour which leads the compiler to random situation?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I think you misunderstood me. I just wanted to see what happens if you explicitly put this import in the target that is **compiling** to see if it's break with the same error.
If it is, then I think the files that used your custom `Category` should not include runtime.h (or include a file that include runtime.h)

Comment: @KIDdAe thanks for a very good idea - work target stopped working with the same error when I added `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to the file which is using `Category`. That means it's better to refactor the name instead of relying that the runtime and `Category` won't meet. I think  this is because of OCMock I included (now I understand, that it surely use runtime)

Comment: A good practice to avoid similar problem is to use prefix for your own classes. By doing this, you should avoid collision with others classes ;) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refactor the name of this class anyway, to avoid such collisions in the future.
And it will be less painful to do it sooner rather than later.

It is probable that you import a file that imports `<objc/runtime.h>` at some point. 
As the matter of what the difference is between the test target and the regular target, on Xcode testing works by injecting the symbols onto a bundle. There might be some differences in code stripping and symbols visibility that could explain this kind of error.

No wonder [Apple recommends to prefix classes with 2 or 3 letters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)

Comment: accepting this, however, you've almost repeated the comments :) The issue with test target is that I added OCMock into libraries, and it imports runtime

Answer (score 1):

Although you should do what @Olotiar says in his answer, there's a quick fix.

Go to your project **Build Settings**, search for "**Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)**" and set the value to **NO**.